# javascript redirect with hash tag

Tags: javascript, browser-history, history.js

I have implemented my website's search results with AJAX, using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). For HTML5 browsers, I have URLs like `http://example.com/search/X6a2/3`, which, in browsers not supporting the History API, does fall back nicely to `http://example.com/search/#X6a2/3`.

However, if a HTML5 URL is opened in an older browser, the new hash tag is appended to the full URL as soon as the page is changed. (for example `http://example.com/search/X6a2/3#/X6a2/4` - ugh!)

All I need is a clean way to redirect to the hash tag-only version as soon as a non-HTML5 browser is detected. `window.location.replace()` seems to ignore the hash tag. What do I do?

Comment: A old browser will not be able to open a non-hash tagged url because the page will not be found.

Comment: not an expert but changing a url is more cleaner using mod_rewite.. i think..

Comment: Can you include the code you are trying to use that is failing? In my (brief) tests `location.replace()` doesn't have a hashtag problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me. Are you sure window.replace is the problem?

```
var href = "http://example.com/search/X6a2/3";
var idx = href.indexOf('search', 0);
var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+7) + "#" + href.slice(idx+7);

alert(new_href);
window.location.replace(new_href);
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work. My code is a mess, so something else was probably stopping it. Thanks :)