# Redirect to the an id of a page with the header function in PHP isn't working

Tags: php, redirect

I'm creating a website that requires a redirect from one page to an id of the same page using PHP. When the header is called it just redirects to the page without the specified id even though it is called in the header function to redirect to the part of the page with the id.

It is supposed to redirect to:

```
header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php#redirect');
```

But it actually directs to:

```
header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php');
```

Is there a problem with my code that is causing this. (By the way this is a continuation of another question, but my code wasn't posted in the other question and I couldn't delete the other question even though I wanted to.)

This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reportsubmit'])) {
    $radio = $_POST['report'];
    if ($radio == 'customer') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#customer">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'item') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#item">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'department') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#department">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'person') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#person">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    }
    $findHttp = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http';
    header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php#redirect');
} else if (isset($_POST['customersubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['itemsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['departmentsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['personsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gordmart MIS Reports</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Main.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="report">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a report grouped by customers, items, sales departments, or sales people?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF;"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="customer"><p>Customers</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="item"><p>Items Sold</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="department"><p>Sales Departments</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="person"><p>Sales People</p>
                <input type="submit" name="reportsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="customer">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all customers, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="customer" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="customer" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="customersubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="item">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales items, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="item" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="item" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="itemsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="department">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales departments, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="department" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="department" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="departmentsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="person">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales people, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="person" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="person" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="personsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="redirect">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <?php echo $redirect;?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the hash is a browser utility. From my understanding, you simply cannot redirect to a URL with a hash from the server side (PHP).

The only way to do this is via javascript. [Here's an answer to a previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135909/javascript-redirect-with-hash-tag) that shows how to do this in JavaScript. In your case  you would have to capture the form submit and then call `window.location.replace` with the appropriate hash.

Answer (score 0):

The hash part is never sent to the server. It only exists in the web browser so you will have to write javascript code to get it. Then of course you can in javascript send it to the server.